# Error trying to parse with \pgfmathparse

Tags: pgfmath, pgfmathparse

I'm trying to evaluate the following expression with \pgfmathparse, but I get error messages:

```
\pgfmathparse{\sqrt{{5.8186/{\pi}}}}\pgfmathresult\
```

Any idea why?

Comment: `\pi` is a character, not the actual value of π.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks, I was suspecting it had something to do with that. Is there another way to pass the 'real' pi (and not just `3.14`, please)?

Comment: My answer would be pretty much the same as Heiko's, except that I didn't know that `pi` was a possible value, so I would use `rad(180)`... Don't ask :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The commands `\sqrt` and `\pi` are used to typeset a square root sign and the Greek letter pi, not for computing values.

You can use a different method:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}

\begin{document}

\fpeval{sqrt(5.8186/pi)}

\fpeval{round(sqrt(5.8186/pi),5)}

\fpeval{trunc(sqrt(5.8186/pi),5)}

\end{document}
```

No need to do two steps.

[image]

Compare with the result of the standard Unix `bc` program:

```
> echo 'sqrt(5.8186/(4*a(1)))' | bc -l
1.36092538507774348937
```

Answer (score 4):

Math expressions in pgf/TikZ use a different syntax than TeX's math typesetting (`sqrt` instead of `\sqrt`, `pi` instead of `\pi`, parentheses instead of braces):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
  \pgfmathparse{sqrt(5.8186/pi)}%
  \pgfmathresult

  % Rounding, three fractional digits
  \pgfmathparse{round(1000*sqrt(5.8186/pi))/1000}%
  \pgfmathresult
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks! BTW, know any way to set the desired decimal precision?

Comment: @Anakhand See updated answer.